# How does one handle the streaming case for leetcode's 487. Max Consecutive Ones II?

Tags: python, algorithm

[Link to question](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones-ii/)

The question asks:

> Given a binary array `nums`, return the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the array if you can flip at most one 0.

I was able to get to the sliding window solution for when I could see the previous values for this question.

However, I can't figure out how to tackle the follow up question that is for streaming.

> Follow up: What if the input numbers come in one by one as an infinite stream? In other words, you can't store all numbers coming from the stream as it's too large to hold in memory. Could you solve it efficiently?

I don't think I have access to the previous values like I did in the sliding window. Do I have to keep a record of where the zeroes show up?

I was able to use the code for easier problem [Max Consecutive Ones I](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones) for the sliding window so I think the sliding window code could be extended for the streaming case.

```
# sliding window approach
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        longestSequence = 0
        left = 0
        right = 0
        maxZeroes = 1   # allows us to modify our code in 1 place if we need more than 1 zero next time
        numZeroes = 0

        for right in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[right] == 0:
                numZeroes += 1
            
            while numZeroes == maxZeroes + 1:
                if nums[left] == 0:
                    numZeroes -= 1
                left += 1


            longestSequence = max(longestSequence, right - left + 1) 

        return longestSequence
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to consider saving previous streamed values anyway. After having seen `n` values, with `m` being the length of the longest string of 1's seen so far, if the `n`th value is `0`, a new string begins at the first `1` after position `n`; if the `n`th value is `1` and it is the `t`th value in a string of `1`'s (`t <= m`), that string is lengthend to `t+1` if the `n+1`'st value is a `1`, else it is terminated, and so on. You just need to maintain the variables `n`, `m` and `t`.

Comment: Could you write this as an answer?

Comment: hereto∞, it appears that @trincot has taken a similar approach.

Comment: I found this explaining it https://leetcode.ca/2017-03-31-487-Max-Consecutive-Ones-II/#algorithm , hope it's helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep a count of the number of consecutive ones, another count for the number of consecutive digits including at most one zero, and then a running maximum of either of those. There is no need to keep track of *positions*:

```
    def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        countwithzero = 0
        countones = 0
        maxcount = 0
        for bit in nums:
            if bit:
                countones += 1
                countwithzero += 1
            else:
                countwithzero = countones + 1
                countones = 0
            maxcount = max(maxcount, countwithzero, countones)

        return maxcount
```

Comment: Could you clarify? I am missing something. I do not see how 2 or more consecutive 1's would not be considered in the longest sequence. We are only allowed to flip one 0. Though an extension to this question could be made for to find the longest sequence if one can only flip `k` 0s.  Shouldn't `countwithzero` be reset to `0` when more than one `0` has been seen?

Comment: `countwithzero` will never count more than one zero. Note that when a zero is encountered, this variable is not incremented. Instead it relies completely on the number of consecutive ones that had been found just before this zero was encountered. This zero (and only this one) will be added to that number. Once that is done `countones` is reset to 0, so that if a *second* zero is found in the next iteration, `countwithzero` will actually *reduce* to 1. `countwithzero` will never have to be reset to 0 during iterations -- think of it.